# Hibernate Include a Select query into a where using criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I'm new to Java Hibernate Criteria request and i have a SQL query to transform to a query using critera. Someone could help me to transform this query example to a query with Criteria ?

This is the Sql query :

```
select service_code, version, s_startdate , v_end_date
from t_bsm_service
where service_code like '10-GPD0001'
and (
    s_startdate = (select max(s_startdate) from t_bsm_service where service_code like '10-GPD0001')
)
order by service_code , s_startdate
```

There is a select into a where and a 'and' so i'm a little lost into this...

Thanks for your help

I tried this Java criteria query :

```
Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(BillingProductBaseView.class, "vsic");
        criteria.setProjection(
                Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("vsic.serviceCode")), "id").add(Projections.property("vsic.serviceVersion"), "serviceVersion"))
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(BillingProductBaseView.class));
        if (!ids.isEmpty()) {
            for (String id : ids) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.like("vsic.serviceCode", id));
            }
List<BillingProductBaseView> billingProductOfferingViewList = criteria.list();
```

Where 'ids' is a method parameter : a list of id given can be null or not.

My BillingProductBaseView.class fields are here :

```
@Table(name = "V_BSM_BILLING_PRODUCT_BASE")
public class BillingProductBaseView implements Serializable {

    /**********************
     * Fields of Service
     **********************/

    @Column(name = "SERVICE_CODE")
    private String serviceCode;

    @Column(name = "SERVICE_VERSION")
    private String serviceVersion;

    @Column(name = "S_STARTDATE")
    private Timestamp sStartDate;
```

I hope my question and example are clear to you.

Comment: mabye it wiil be usefull https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries

Comment: I've already seen that article but i don't use criteriaBuilder but Criteria